# Deployment error when upgrade Magento cloud 2.4.4 to php8.1

Tags: magento2-cloud

When updated .magento.app.yaml php version to 8.1, the deployment to magento cloud failed and showed the error below:

```
  Executing build hook...
    W: Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
    W: Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
    W: Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
    W: 
    W:   Problem 1
    W:     - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin is locked to version 2.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    W:     - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 2.3.0 requires composer-plugin-api >=1.1.0 <2.3.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    W:   Problem 2
    W:     - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 2.3.0 requires composer-plugin-api >=1.1.0 <2.3.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.3.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    W:     - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p1 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^2.2.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[2.3.0].
    W:     - magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.4.4-p1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    W: 
  
  E: Error building project: Step failed with status code 2.

E: Error: Unable to build application, aborting.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `composer.lock` used Composer v2 (composer-plugin-api) inside it.

You might want to update your `.magento.app.yaml` and switch to using Composer v2, by default Magento Cloud will use Composer v1.

To do that, update your file as per the following

```
# This file describes an application. You can have multiple applications
# in the same project.


# The name of this app. Must be unique within a project.
name: mymagento

# The toolstack used to build the application.
type: php:8.1
build:
    flavor: none

# Composer v2 for faster deployment
dependencies:
    php:
        composer/composer: '^2.0'

....

hooks:
    # We run build hooks before your application has been packaged.
    build: |
        set -e
        composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/build/generate.xml
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/build/transfer.xml
    # We run deploy hook after your application has been deployed and started.
    deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/deploy.xml
    # We run post deploy hook to clean and warm the cache. Available with ECE-Tools 2002.0.10.
    post_deploy: |
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools run scenario/post-deploy.xml


....
```

Comment: Finally found that it works if i limited composer not greater than 2.2 . type: php:8.1
build:
    flavor: none

dependencies:
    php:
        composer/composer: '>=2.0 <2.2'